# HtmlHelper function to populate dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate a dropdown control in ASP.NET MVC. I have a table named City and i am getting the records from this table to populate through entity data. I have used the ViewBag to add dynamically. However it throws a compilation error.

**Code**

**- View**

```
<h4>City through db</h4>
@Html.DropDownList(cities, "Select City");
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ActionFilterdbEntities db = new ActionFilterdbEntities();
            var cities = db.Cities;
            ViewBag.cities = new SelectList(cities, "Id", "CityName");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
   [Table("City")]
    public class clCity
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Db**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City] (
    [Id]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [CityName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to construct the dropdown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("nameOfTheField", (SelectList)ViewBag.cities, "Select city");
```

If you are putting this dropdown in a form and lets suppose you have a model like this:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

then you would set the code like below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityId", (SelectList)ViewBag.cities, "Select city");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your View should look like:

```
<h4>City through db</h4>
@Html.DropDownList("YourInputId", (SelectList)ViewBag.cities, "Select City")
```

First argument is a `string` that will renter as `id` and `name` attributes of `select` tag.

Answer (score 1):

How about like this,

```
 @{
   SelectList cities = ViewBag.cities;
  }
 @Html.DropDownList("YourDropDownId", cities, "Select City")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList("cities", ViewBag.cities as SelectList,"Select City")
```

please use above code.